# Converting 1 D tensor to 2 D tensor in tensor flow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow2.0, tensor

Below is my sample code

```
sample = np.array([-7.0,-4.0,-1.0,2.0,5.0,8.0,11.0,14.0,15.0])
sample = tf.convert_to_tensor(sample)
tf.reshape(sample, shape=(3,3)),X.ndim
```

How to convert this 1D tensor to 2D tensor, I am bit confused. I tried multiple ways but it is always returning ndim as 1.

Could anyone please help

Comment: You're not assigning the result to anything. You probably want `sample = tf.reshape(sample, shape=(3,3))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. You reshaped your array into 3 rows and 3 columns,which is 2-dimensional array and same has shown in the output.

```
sample = np.array([-7.0,-4.0,-1.0,2.0,5.0,8.0,11.0,14.0,15.0])
sample = tf.convert_to_tensor(sample)
tf.reshape(sample, shape=(3,3))
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[-7., -4., -1.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  8.],
       [11., 14., 15.]])>
```

and to check the dimensions of the array, you can simply attach the .ndim at the end of the code.

```
tf.reshape(sample, shape=(3,3)).ndim        #remove (,X) from the code as X has no assignments
```

Output:

```
2
```